# Convert HTML element ID to string for comparison

Tags: html, string, comparison, string-conversion

Is it possible to use the value of this.id from the following HTML code in a comparison ?

```
<div id="Kids Bikes" class="album" onClick="javascript:loadPopupContent(this.id)">  
        <img src="images/kidsbikes/1.jpg" class="uitgelicht" >
        <div style="background-color:rgba(240, 124, 0, 0.6)" class="overlay"><p class="overlayx">Kids Bikes</p></div> 
</div>
```

I'm creating a photoalbum. When a visitor clicks a photo a popup shows up with thumbnails from photos of the album the user clicked. This function is used to create a popup:

```
function loadPopupContent(id){
//centering with css
centerPopup();
//load popup
loadPopup();
// load content
loadContent(id);
```

}

The loadContent function looks like this,  but it doesn't do anything. I think it's because i'm trying to compare a string with a HTML element, but i'm not sure. When I remove the if (albumname == 'AllroundBikes'){}else{} statement, everything works fine.

```
function loadContent(eleId){
if (eleId != 0){

    var albumnaam = eleId.replace("-","");
    var albumname = albumnaam.replace(" ","");

    if (albumname == 'AllroundBikes'){ // 5 foto's
        $("#popupContent").html("<h1>" + eleId + "</h1>" +
        "<a class='thumbnail' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/1.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/1.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" + 
        "<a class='thumbnail' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/2.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/2.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailr' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/3.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/3.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailr' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/4.jpg class='uitgelichtvakr' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/4.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnail' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/5.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/5.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>");
    } 
    else if {       
        $("#popupContent").html("<h1>" + eleId + "</h1>" +
        "<a class='thumbnail' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/1.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/1.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" + 
        "<a class='thumbnail' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/2.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/2.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailr' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/3.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/3.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailr' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/4.jpg class='uitgelichtvakr' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/4.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnail' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/5.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/5.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnail' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/6.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/6.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailr' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/7.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/7.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailr' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/8.jpg class='uitgelichtvakr' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/8.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailo' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/9.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/9.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailo' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/10.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/10.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailro' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/11.jpg class='uitgelichtvak' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/11.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>" +
        "<a class='thumbnailro' href='#thumb'><img src=images/" + albumname + "/12.jpg class='uitgelichtvakr' /><span><img src=images/" + albumname + "/12.jpg height='415' width='750'/></a>");

} 
else {
    $("#popupContent").html("<h1>Empty</h1>");
}
```

}

Comment: FYI: `id` attributes may not contain any spaces according to both the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and [HTML 5 draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute). If you want to follow this spec, then you'll most likely have to tweak your design and store your album names in a different attribute instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

By this you get the id of element in consideration as text.

```
 $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `this.id` is perfectly possible in HTML.
However I notice your element ID has a space in between? That's unusual - I'm not sure that's legal, but the general syntax is correct.

Edit:
The click handler in HTML is `onclick`(lower case c), that could be the problem too.